# Rails 4 - how to display a collection of associated content in a view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I'm trying to figure out how to display a collection of associated data in my view.

I have models for User, Profile and Evaluation.

The associations are:

User

```
has_one :profile
has_many :given_evaluations, foreign_key: :evaluator_id, dependent: :destroy, class_name: Evaluation
  has_many :received_evaluations, foreign_key: :evaluatee_id, dependent: :destroy, class_name: Evaluation
```

Profile

```
belongs_to :user
```

Evaluation

```
belongs_to :evaluator, foreign_key: :evaluator_id, class_name: User
  belongs_to :evaluatee, foreign_key: :evaluatee_id, class_name: User
```

In my profile show, I'm trying to show a user's received evaluations. I think the following is correct, although it's not working.

```
<% @profile.user.received_evaluations.each do | receval | %>
                        <ul class="testimonial-slider text-white text-center">
                            <li>
                                <div class="testimonial-content">
                                    <%= receval.remark %>
                                </div>
```

I can see in my rails console, that this user has 1 received evaluation:

```
 p.user.received_evaluations
     => #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Evaluation id: 4, evaluatee_id: 34, overall_score: nil, project_score: nil, personal_score: nil, remark: "testing", work_again?: nil, continue_project?: nil, created_at: "2016-06-03 08:15:04", updated_at: "2016-06-03 08:15:04", evaluator_id: nil>]>
```

The remark in that evaluation is "testing".

When I try this - the profile view renders, but the remark does not show. It's just a blank view.

Can anyone see what I've done wrong?

I have tried each of the following the code (without the html and styling), but in each case, I get a "no method error for remark". I can't figure out what that error message means - remark is not a method.

```
<%= @profile.user.received_evaluations.first.try(:remark) %>
<%= @profile.user.received_evaluations.try(:remark) %>
<%= @profile.user.received_evaluations.remark %>
```

Comment: If your query is right, make sure that its not causing by your `html` or `css` issues. Check first without the `html` tags.

Comment: @ruby_newbie - remark is the name of the attribute in the evaluation table that I'm trying to display

Comment: If you put a debugger in the view what is a receval?  Also if you put a normal string in that class will it show up?

Comment: it's the short name given to the do block

Comment: I know that.  I mean if you put <%- binding.pry %> with the pry gem installed it will open a console.  you can type in "receval" and it will show you what your first receval object is.

Comment: @M.Karim I tried removing the do block and trying without css html - my attempts are pasted above. They each give errors. The css and styling works fine with out the ruby methods in the code, if i just type plain text, it all works fine

Comment: @ruby_newbie the console output is shown above

Comment: does `Profile.user.received_evaluations.first` return an output in your console?

Comment: Yes: p.user.received_evaluations.first
 => #<Evaluation id: 4, evaluatee_id: 34, overall_score: nil, project_score: nil, personal_score: nil, remark: "testing", work_again?: nil, continue_project?: nil, created_at: "2016-06-03 08:15:04", updated_at: "2016-06-03 08:15:04", evaluator_id: nil>

Comment: okay change `<% @profile.user.received_evaluations.each do | receval | %>` to `<% @profile.user.received_evaluations.map do | receval | %>` and see if your view shows anything this time

Comment: You need to use `<% byebug %> ` or `<% binding.pry %>` in your block. And check if the `@profile.user.received_evaluations` returns something or not.

Comment: The console shows the returns.

Comment: @ollaollu - i tried, but I still get a blank page in the view. It doesn't show anything

Comment: Hmm.. if `p.user.received_evaluations.first.remark` displays an output in your console then it should actually turn up in your views. Then iterating `@profile.user.received_evaluations` with `map` should have fixed it. Might want to debug your view code a bit further

Comment: No idea why its not working. So frustrating. Any tips on where to find resources about debugging this kind of problem?

Comment: Docs. Look more into `CollectionProxy`

Comment: Can you post the exact and full error message you're seeing? The one above doesn't look quite right.

Comment: @TylerFerraro I don't get an error with the text in the block - i just get a blank view. If I try adding the above variations (without the block), I get this error: undefined method `remark' for #<Evaluation::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x007f966916cf68>

Comment: `<%= @profile.user.received_evaluations.first.try(:remark) %>` this one should work.   Are you sure `@profile` is the same as `p` in the console?

Comment: @Jack - yes I'm sure they are the same. It doesn't work. It gives the error I set out above.

Comment: I meant `<%= @profile.user.received_evaluations.first.try(:remark) %>` before (edited).

Comment: How is `@profile` loaded/set exactly in the controller?  Do it exactly the same way in the console plus `.user.received_evaluations.first`.

Comment: @Jack - your edited suggestion also doesnt work. the page loads, without error, but does not display the remark. I can generate the result in the console, using the flow I set out above.

Comment: You would need to show us full controller action code and full view code.  Is it a partial?

Comment: @Jack which controller action are you looking to see? Yes- it's a partial.

Comment: I can't begin to understand why I can have a result in the console but not in the code

Comment: The one that is loading/setting the `@profile`.  If it's a parital then is anything else from the partial rendering?  Maybe you have `<% render ... %>` instead of `<%= render ... %>`? :)

Comment: The partial renders. It gives me a background image as well as a button to read more feedback. The feedback itself does not work. I don't know what you mean by the controller action that loads the profile. I don't understand what that means.

Comment: Where do you have the `@profile` variable from?

Comment: Anyway, all looks good to me, so if the partial works then the `@profile` (or specifically the `user`) must be different from the one you use in the console, and just has no `received_evaluations` (maybe because of different db or different env, or it's just a different profile).

Comment: Hi @Jack, I don't know what that means either. Sorry - I'm missing something in your question. My profile controller has a before action that  sets the profile, but I don't know what you mean about how that action is set. before_action :set_profile, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

Comment: Yea, ok, so then I mean the code/body of `set_profile`.

Comment: @Jack - thanks for your thoughts. I'm sure its the same profile and the same user. I printed the ids to check. Those render in the profile view. The db and the env are both the same too.

Comment: Its: def set_profile
      @profile = Profile.find(params[:id])
     
    end

Comment: If you are sure they're the same then dunno ;). Maybe just check also what `<%= debug @profile %><%= debug @profile.user %><%= debug @profile.user.received_evaluations %>` renders?

Comment: Something strange is happening. I turned off my computer, turned it on again, restarted the server and now it works. I have saved all my code at least 20 times prior to trying that. Is it possible that the browser holds onto old code for a while, even when you restart the server?